# Load Nib as Subview causes Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nib

I created a `nib` that I use as a kind of overlay for messages. 
Problem is that the view controller doesn't free the memory, instead it increases it everytime the controller is called. I tired to remove the subview, but has no effect:

[image]

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        //init Msg Overlay
        msgOverlay = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MsgOverlay", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? MsgOverlay
        msgOverlay.center = AnimationEngine.offScreenLeftPosition
        msgOverlay.delegate = self
        msgOverlay.msgType = .Save
        self.view.addSubview(msgOverlay)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated:Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)         

        view.subviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        } 
    }
```

Comment: is MsgOverlay's delegate property a weak property?

Comment: not it's not `var delegate: msgOverlayDelegate?` when i want to make it weak, compiler says "weak may only be applied to class and class-bound types no "msgOverlayDelegate' "which is the protocol ??

Comment: you can add "protocol msgOverlayDelegate:class {//...}" to make it be able to set as weak property. If it is not weak, you have a reference cycle between the viewcontroller and the overlay object. It may cause the memory leak if you keep load this view controller class, instead of reusing one controller instance.

Comment: got it, had to add class to the protocol, `protocol msgOverlayDelegate: class {..`than i could make the delegate weak. memory leak is gone. thx